# Gif animation does not restart on new page...?

Tags: javascript, animation, gif

I made a GIF animation running for a few seconds, and is **not** looped. When I put the gif on different pages, the animation does not restart because its cached... it just stays on the last frame. How can I make it restart when it is on a new page? I know of ways how to rename it or add "?" to it, but it will give me bandwidth issues.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191922/restart-an-animated-gif-from-javascript-without-reloading-the-image

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I highly doubt this is possible, without forcing the browser to reload the image (also possible by denying caching), but, as you said, that will result in a higher bandwidth use.