# How to choose between `window.URL.createObjectURL()` and `window.webkitURL.createObjectURL()` based on browser

Tags: javascript, html, dom

From the Firefox developer website, I know that Firefox uses

```
objectURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

to get url of file type, but in chrome and other webkit browsers we have `window.webkitURL.createObjectURL()` for detecting url.

I don't know how to swap this functions based on browser engines, and I need it to be worked on both browsers (Chrome and firefox)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.URL.createObjectURL

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could define a wrapper function:

```
function createObjectURL ( file ) {
    if ( window.webkitURL ) {
        return window.webkitURL.createObjectURL( file );
    } else if ( window.URL && window.URL.createObjectURL ) {
        return window.URL.createObjectURL( file );
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
// works cross-browser
var url = createObjectURL( file );
```

Comment: I think this is not anymore necessary as when I used this in the code Chrome return  "webkitURL' is deprecated. Please use 'URL' instead." message in the console.

Answer (score 25):

Simple one liner:

```
var createObjectURL = (window.URL || window.webkitURL || {}).createObjectURL || function(){};
```

Comment: If the `createObjectURL` method doesn't exist in the browser, the variable will be `undefined`, and trying to invoke it will throw an error.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas That is correct but wasn't part of the question. It is now fixed in a way that won't have any overhead for each additional call.

Answer (score 9):

```
if (window.URL !== undefined) {
    window.URL.createObjectURL();
} else if (window.webkitURL !== undefined) {
    window.webkitURL.createObjectURL();
} else {
    console.log('Method Unavailable: createObjectURL');
}
```

Is round-about what you're looking for. Also, [THIS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example%3a_Using_object_URLs_to_display_images) example uses the much simpler...

```
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
```