# URL.createObjectURL for audio blob gives TypeError in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, webrtc, getusermedia

I'm trying to create a Object URL from an audio blob created from `getUserMedia`. The code works within Chrome, but there are problems in Firefox.

The error:

When I call `stopAudioRecorder()` it stops at `audio_player.src = URL.createObjectURL(audio_blob);`

`TypeError: Argument 1 is not valid for any of the 2-argument overloads of URL.createObjectURL.`

Code:

```
  var stopAudioRecorder = function(audio_recorder) {
    var audio_blob, audio_player, new_recording, save_button;

    audio_recorder.stopRecording();
    audio_blob = audio_recorder.getBlob();

    audio_player = document.createElement("audio");
    audio_player.src = URL.createObjectURL(audio_blob);
    audio_player.controls = true;
    audio_player.play();

    $('#new_recording').appendChild(audio_player);

    recording = false;
    return ($("#record_button")).text("Start recording");
  };
```

I attempted to provide some cross-browser compatibility by adding a wrapper function

```
function createObjectURL ( file ) {
    if ( window.webkitURL ) {
        return window.webkitURL.createObjectURL( file );
    } else if ( window.URL && window.URL.createObjectURL ) {
        return window.URL.createObjectURL( file );
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

from [How to choose between `window.URL.createObjectURL()` and `window.webkitURL.createObjectURL()` based on browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277677/javascript-newbie-how-to-choose-between-window-url-createobjecturl-and-window), but that didn't work

Comment: try, `audio_player.mozSrcObject = audio_blob;`

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox you can directly give the media stream created by getUserMedia to the "mozSrcObject" attribute of the audio element. So the following code should work:

```
audio_player.mozSrcObject = audio_blob;
```

You should consider using the [adapter.js](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/webrtc/tree/master/samples/web/js) file to account for browser differences.

Comment: What about if you need the URL?

Comment: works for me , just check browser : navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') != -1

Comment: Your link is broken