# Get image base64 with reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the content of an image in a base64 string.

Originally I was doing it with [`readAsDataURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) but [because I want to validate the `mimetype` on the client side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29672957/1081396), it seems I have to use readAsArrayBuffer as also pointed out [on this site](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/determine-an-images-type-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=s7zkuy_gxk3).

So prevoiusly I had this working fine:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function(event) {
    var base64 = reader.result;
};

reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
```

[Reproduction online](https://jsfiddle.net/3L7x6suh/3/)

Now I added the mimetype validation and I have the following:

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onloadend = function(event) {

    var realMimeType = getRealMimeType(reader);

    if (realMimeType !== 'unknown') {
        var emptyBufferArray = reader.result; //nothing
    }else{
        alert("Invalid mime type!");
    }
};

reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0]); //<-- notice the difference
```

[Reproduction online](https://jsfiddle.net/3L7x6suh/13/) (not getting the base64 string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way I found of doing it was to use two different `FileReader` instances, one inside the other.

[Reproduction online](https://jsfiddle.net/3L7x6suh/27/)

Javascript

```
$(document).on('change', '#upload', addBackgroundImage);

function addBackgroundImage(event) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var readerBase64 = new FileReader();
    var image = event.target.files[0];

    reader.onloadend = function() {
        var realMimeType = getRealMimeType(reader);
        if (realMimeType !== 'unknown') {
            readerBase64.readAsDataURL(image);
        } else {
            alert("Please upload a valid image file");
        }
    };

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(image);

    readerBase64.onloadend = function(){
        var base64 = this.result;
        $('.bg').css('background-image', 'url('+base64+')');
    };

    $('#upload').val('');
}

function getRealMimeType(reader){
    var arr = (new Uint8Array(reader.result)).subarray(0, 4);
    var header = '';
    var realMimeType;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        header += arr[i].toString(16);
    }

    // magic numbers: http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html
    switch (header) {
        case "89504e47":
            realMimeType = "image/png";
            break;
        case "47494638":
            realMimeType = "image/gif";
            break;
        case "ffd8ffDB":
        case "ffd8ffe0":
        case "ffd8ffe1":
        case "ffd8ffe2":
        case "ffd8ffe3":
        case "ffd8ffe8":
            realMimeType = "image/jpeg";
            break;
        default:
            realMimeType = "unknown"; // Or you can use the blob.type as fallback
            break;
    }

    return realMimeType;
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="upload" />
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Comment: Where did you get the list of magic bytes? Be good to mention that, but +1 in anycase.

Comment: Don't remember the exact source, but googlying a bit. You can find some of them in here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Comment: Ok thanks. Seems like there is no "go to" reference for this. I found info here (http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/PRONOM/Default.aspx) but not the easiest site to navigate.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't manage yet to use `base64` but I found a way to do it using `blob`.
If you find a way to do it using `base64` please add your answer.

Right now my image string looks like this, which I believe will generate me some problems:

```
 background-image: url("blob:https%3A//fiddle.jshell.net/214b3c01-5b38-4aae-b839-e35cf57a5190");
```

---

I got the hint from a fiddle about [how to render a retrieved image as a blob URL](https://jsfiddle.net/Jan_Miksovsky/yy7Zs/)

Then I just applied it to my code with [a little improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11277728/1081396) and voila!!

[Reproduction online](https://jsfiddle.net/3L7x6suh/22/)
Working in IE> 9, Chrome, Firefox...

Whole code:

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="upload" />
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).on('change', '#upload', addBackgroundImage);

function addBackgroundImage(event) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function(event) {
        var realMimeType = getRealMimeType(reader);

        if (realMimeType !== 'unknown') {
            var base64 = reader.result;

            var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array( this.result );
            var blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: realMimeType } );
            var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL || {}.createObjectURL;
            var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL( blob );

            $('.bg').css('background-image', 'url('+imageUrl+')');
        } else {
            alert("Please upload a valid image file");
        }
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0]);
     $('#upload').val('');
}

function getRealMimeType(reader){
    var arr = (new Uint8Array(reader.result)).subarray(0, 4);
    var header = '';
    var realMimeType;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        header += arr[i].toString(16);
    }

    // magic numbers: http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html
    switch (header) {
        case "89504e47":
            realMimeType = "image/png";
            break;
        case "47494638":
            realMimeType = "image/gif";
            break;
        case "ffd8ffDB":
        case "ffd8ffe0":
        case "ffd8ffe1":
        case "ffd8ffe2":
        case "ffd8ffe3":
        case "ffd8ffe8":
            realMimeType = "image/jpeg";
            break;
        default:
            realMimeType = "unknown"; // Or you can use the blob.type as fallback
            break;
    }

    return realMimeType;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this ["stolen"](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/blob/cbbec3a6c6b0b74d1502f3a32d5c6e575360886c/demo/src/main/webapp/js/ng-file-upload.js#L2259-L2267) function:

```
function arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
  let binary = '';
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  const len = bytes.byteLength;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
  }
  return window.btoa(binary);
}
```

Comment: It works, but is there a performance concern?  the `for` loop and the `binary += ` are executed too many times.

Comment: I rewrite the `+=` parts to below code: 
`function arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
            var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
            var chars = [];
            
            var len = bytes.byteLength;
            for (let i=0; i<len; i++) {
                chars.push(String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]))
            }
            
            var binary = chars.join('');
            return window.btoa(binary);
        }`

Answer (score 1):

The solution below worked for me using just one FileReader :

```
reader.onloadend = function(event) {
    const arrayBuffer = reader.result;
    const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], {type: 'image/png'});
    let src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
};
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0]);
```

hope that helps!