# Ionic 5 File opener Issue is file not found

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic5

I am use Ionic with angular and make one app. In my app i use couch DB for the download image.

I am using *Android Phone*.

I am trying to download my file with help of file opener and **i got** ->

> (Status:9 message:file not found)

```
   <ion-item mode=md class="input-group ion-no-padding viewFile" lines=none *ngIf="common.isDocumentFill">
     <span (click)="doc(fc)">View File</span>
    </ion-item>
```

//function

```
doc(objFC) {

    let obj = {
      ServiceId: 1,
      CouchDBDocId: objFC.CouchDBDocId,
      DocumentName: objFC.FileName
    }
    this.api.getPdf(obj).subscribe((data: any) => {
     // debugger
      let blob = new Blob([data], { type: data.type });

      var downloadURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
      var types = data.type
      this.down(downloadURL, types)
    }); 
 }
  down(filepath, mimeType) {
    this.fileOpener.open(filepath, mimeType)
     .then(() =>
     console.log('File is opened')
      )
     .catch(e => console.log('Error opening file', e)); 
    }
```

and Service

```
 getPdf(obj) {

    // debugger
    const httpOptions = {
      responseType: 'blob' as 'json'
    };

    return this.http.post(this.url + "DocumentDetails/DownloadFile", obj, httpOptions);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please install required plugins

```
1.import { FileOpener } from '@ionic-native/file-opener/ngx';    
2.import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
```

make instansts in constructor

```
  constructor(
         private fileOpener: FileOpener,
         private file: File
         )
```

put this function in your ts file

```
openPDF (stringBase64PDF) {
                debugger
                fetch('data:application/pdf;base64,' + stringBase64PDF, {
                    method: "GET"
                })
                .then(res => res.blob()).then(blob => {
                  console.log("created blob");
                  this.file.createFile(this.file.dataDirectory, 'temp.pdf', true)
                  .then(() => {
                    console.log("file created");
                    this.file.writeFile(this.file.dataDirectory, 'temp.pdf', blob, { replace: true })
                    .then(res => {
                      console.log("file writed");
                      this.fileOpener.open(res.toInternalURL(), 'application/pdf')
                      .then((res) => {
                        console.log('file opened')
                      }).catch(err => {
                        console.log('open error')
                      });
                    }).catch(err => {
                      console.log('write error')     
                    });
                  }).catch(() => {
                    console.log("create error");
                  })
                  
                }).catch(err => {
                  console.log('blob error')
                });
              }
```

put in html file

```
  <ion-item (click)="openPDF(base64pdf)">
             <ion-label>Click here to open pdf file</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to create the URL like

```js
var downloadURL = (window.webkitURL || window.URL).createObjectURL(data);
```

The browser might not support `window.URL` -> [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277677/how-to-choose-between-window-url-createobjecturl-and-window-webkiturl-creat)
Also do you mean an iOS device or Android when talking about phone?

Comment: I have blob object, the issue is ` link.click ` is not working in phone.

Comment: Please define what do you mean by phone? Which OS?

Comment: my phone Android