# Onclick play GIF image with jQuery and start from beginning

Tags: jquery, onclick, reload, gif, animated-gif

I have a website with images on it. Some of the images are animated GIF images. What I've done is to show a static image of the GIF and on a click event, the actual GIF images is displayed.

Here is my code:

JQuery

```
$(".theimage").click(function() {
$(this).addClass('hidden');
$(this).next().removeClass('hidden');
});
$(".theimage2").click(function() {
 $(this).addClass('hidden');
$(this).prev().removeClass('hidden');
});
```

HTML

```
<img class="theimage" src="image_static.gif" alt=""/>

<img class="theimage2 hidden" src="image_animated.gif" alt=""/>
```

CSS

```
.hidden{
display:none !important;
}
```

I am changing the class of the previous and next elements because I may have more than one GIF image on a single page, thus preventing the action of occurring for all of them.

So far so good, the script works. What I am trying to achieve actually is for the GIF image to always start from the beginning. At the moment it only does so the first time. Then, it looks like it continues playing in the background and on the second call, it simply continues playing. Sometimes even it freezes, something to do with cache I guess.

How can i accomplish this?

Comment: Could you give us a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: When an image is hidden it doesn't stop, it just keeps playing in the background.  I think you will need to either remove the `img` element and re-add it to it's parent, or change its `src` attribute when it is show/hidden.

Comment: How can i re-add it to it's parent?

Comment: Or change its src attribute when its show/hidden ?

Comment: Like this: `var el=$('#bla'),parent=e.parent();  /*remove*/el.remove();  /*re-add*/parent.append(el);`

Comment: Can you do the example with the code that i already have here?

Comment: Yes, I'm working on it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restart an animated GIF from JavaScript without reloading the image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191922/restart-an-animated-gif-from-javascript-without-reloading-the-image)

Comment: I'm trying something like this : `var src = $('.theimage2 img').attr('src');
img1 = new Image();
img1.src = src;$(".theimage2 img").click(function() {
$(this).attr('src', img1.src);
});`

Comment: I'm trying something like this : `var src = $('.theimage2 img').attr('src');
img1 = new Image();
img1.src = src;$(".theimage2 img").click(function() {
$(this).attr('src', img1.src);
});` and it does work, however when i use more than one GIF image on a single page, the action is occurring for all of them. How can i prevent this ?

Comment: Your jQuery is wrong - use `$("img.theimage2")` instead of `$(".theimage2 img")`.

Comment: Is actually reloading the animated GIF like i want 'BUT' I'm using more than one GIF image on a single page, the action is occurring for all of them. How can i prevent this ?

Comment: Please refer to my answer in another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191922/restart-an-animated-gif-from-javascript-without-reloading-the-image/38365667#38365667.

Answer (score 6):

this would be a solution to larger images [Restart an animated GIF from JavaScript without reloading the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191922/restart-an-animated-gif-from-javascript-without-reloading-the-image)

in a nut shell load the image into a javascript variable then change out the src on click

```
$(function(){
    var image = new Image();
       image.src='http://rack.3.mshcdn.com/media/ZgkyMDEyLzEwLzE5LzExXzMzXzMzXzE3Nl9maWxlCnAJdGh1bWIJMTIwMHg    5NjAwPg/462b8072';
     $('#img').click(function(){
       $(this).attr('src',image.src);
     }); 
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GS427/1/

its ugly i couldnt find the right image for the starting but you can see that it starts in the same place every time

Comment: I know that works, however, when the GIF image is larger in size, let's say 2-3MB, it takes some time for it to load

Comment: if you loaded it hidden somewhere else it would grab the cached version (assuming their browser settings allow it...."

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide mouse event to mousedown and mouseup, perform hiding first and showing second or viceversa on mousedown then
perform hiding first and showing second or viceversa on up,