# Need to active action on hover and back to original in 7 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, gif

Im developing a site that contains few animation effects.

1. I need to active gif(animation) on hover then once the courser is off it will be static again.
2. On hover I need Image1 to disappear and show image2 then once the mouse is gone, image1 will appear again after 7 seconds.

ex. Image1 is a tv with curtains, once the mouse is on it, image1 will disappear and show image2 then after 7 seconds image one will appear again.

What is the best way to pull this off?

Comment: you can achieve with `javascript` and `css3` only, but `jquery` will clarify your code and make your life easier...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try something like:

```
$("#myStaticImage").mouseenter(function(){

$("#myHiddenGif").fadeIn().delay(7000).fadeOut()

})
```

EDIT: It works better with mouseenter instead of hover

The hiddenGif should be over the static one, but with display: none

Check my example here: [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e9Lrv49c/2/)

[jQuery .delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked great for the second option. But for option 1, the gif appears but it does not reload. once the gif showed the animation it does not reshow the animation unless the page reloads.

Is it possible to reload gif on hover?

Comment: The best way to do that is with an infinite gif animation. Or check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191922/restart-an-animated-gif-from-javascript-without-reloading-the-image

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jquery like this:

```
$("#your_image_id").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).attr('src')="http://some-gif-img-source"
});

$("#your_image_id").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).attr('src')="http://static-img-source"
});
```